# Can't find CONFIG_PCI on menuconfig

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to enable the CONFIG_PCI option on a custom kernel I work with, but can't find the option. Searching from the menuconfig screen, I see that CONFIG_PCI should be located under the 'Bus Support' menu, and that it depends on CONFIG_MIGHT_HAVE_PCI. Searching for this option gives me the following output:

```
Symbol: MIGHT_HAVE_PCI [=n]
Type  : boolean
```

So, I can't find any of the configurations I'm interested in... Can anyone give me a clue on how to find these ellusive options?

Comment: Example kernel 4.1.7, /boot/config : There are ~113 lines with [CONFIG PCI*] ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNS1pfeXpRRGU1ZFU/view?usp=sharing -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working on an ARM kernel (`MIGHT_HAVE_PCI` is only used for `arc` and `arm`). As you noticed, `CONFIG_PCI` depends on `CONFIG_MIGHT_HAVE_PCI`; the latter isn't a user-selectable option, it's a setting selected by ARM platforms, *via* the "ARM system type" option, or specific SoCs or machines, via their own options (*e.g.* "AT91RM9200" in the Atmel SoCs). You need to choose the appropriate system type, and possibly modify it so that it selects `MIGHT_HAVE_PCI`. See [`arch/arm/Kconfig`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig) for details.